# Matching classes in any order

Tags: css

I need to match an element that has 2 classes. Below is some samples of the HTML:

```
<i class="img _3odc img"></i>
```

And

```
<i class="img img"></i>
```

I am currently using the following, but it fails if the order of `img img` is different:

```
i[class*="img img"]
```

I assumed (assumptions are bad I know) that using `contains` would match if they are in any order. I have no idea why there's 2 class names the same, I just have to work with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to select only those images that contain 2 ocurrences of the img class in their class list, is that correct?

Comment: @Shaggy yes. But the occurrences can appear in any order. My solution works if they're in order, but doesn't if they are not.

Comment: Why would you have an element that has the same class repeated?

Comment: I don't think you can easily check if a class name is repeated.

Comment: @j08691 ask Facebook, it's their code. I have no idea why they have done it. Probably to stop bots and cause developers to face the same issue as I am. Although it's easy to get around when scraping, I just wanted to see if it was possible with CSS selectors alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix two equals classNames. Avoid to make it in the html. CSS will not work with two equals classes in the same element.

See the conflict working:

```css
.same {
  color:green;
}
.same.same {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="same same">Test</div>
<div class="same">Test 2</div>
```

### EDIT

Even if it's an invalid HTML and a weird mode, try this:

```
i[class*="img "][class*=" img"]
```

Note the spaces.

```css
i[class*="img "][class*=" img"] {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<i class="img otherClass img">test</i>
<i class="img img otherClass">test</i>
```

Comment: As I have stated, I am not in control of the HTML. I am writing a data mining tool. I use CSS to target the elements in the source to extract the data (HtmlAgilityPack/Fizzler C#). This doesn't provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: The answer is still useless to me.

Comment: I know that's not your culprit, but this mode mixing the same classname in the same element is not valid and very very dangerous. So if this works for you, my pleasure to assist you. And sorry for the first answer, because I can't understand why you are making it (now I know you're not guilty `;)`)